# Python configparser automatically convert to bools

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

I am writing a class to parse various config files. It contains methods for `yaml` files and `ini` + `cfg` files.

Parsing yamls works fine, but I have a problem with those two other ones. Basically I read them, I parse them, but if e.g. my `config.cfg` file looks like this:

```
[foo]
bar: True
```

The value for `config['foo']['bar']` will be `'True'`, not `True`, so I end up with a string.

I don't want to force the users of my class to convert the given value. Is there a way to get around this, so the strings become booleans?

P.S After reading a configuration I convert return a dictionary of read values, like this:

```py
config_parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
config_parser.read(config_file_path)
return {section: dict(config_parser.items(section)) for section in config_parser.sections()}
```